# How can I send a html selector's option into Controller using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, frontend

I have multiple city options in my Selector in view, and I need to use the city name in a Controller method. The JavaScript function I want to use will be trigered when clicked on a button. before, I used

```
window.location = "/results";
```

in my JavaScript, the "/results" being the route I use my Controller in. but you clearly can't send any data to Controller this way (or can you?). The only method I could find online was using ajax, but I want to stay out of ajax as far as I can. So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a http POST request in plain JavaScript? If so see [MDN Web API Reference - XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Or are you asking how to put data in a URL, e.g. `window.location = "/results?select=1"`?

Comment: I was asking in general for any way that might help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no one answered this question, I tried my luck and found the solution. So what we need to do is first, getting the value of the selector we need, and then sending it into our controller using a URL. Here's the JavaScript function that triggers with the click of a button:

```
var city = document.getElementById('citypicker').value;
window.location.href = "/results/"+city;
```

The first line retrieves the value of selector with the id of 'citypicker', stores it in **city** variable and then we redirect to a URL consisting of that **city** variable. So this URL changes every time we select another value.

In the route, we define this URL as such:

```
Route::get('/results/{city}', 'ResultsController@city');
```

the {city} is variable, meaning that it can change AND can be used as input of city method in ResultsController. So the method looks like this:

```
public function city($city) {
    //code here
}
```

No ajax was used either. Hope this helps.

Comment: Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg. Yes, I thought someone might need a solution in the future and this might be helpful.